# Getting error using Laravel PayPal billing agreement

Tags: laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm getting an error using Laravel PayPal billing agreement. I received HTTP response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-agreements/. I'm
getting this error once I try to complete the agreement process.

[image: Laravel/Paypal error]

```
$id = my_created_plan_id

protected function agreement($id) 
{
    $agreement = new Agreement();
    $agreement->setName('Base Agreement')->setDescription('Basic Agreement') 
    // ->setStartDate(date("Y-m-d").'T9:45:04Z'); ->setStartDate('2021-07-05T9:45:04Z');

    $agreement->setPlan($this->Plan($id));
    $agreement->setPayer($this->payer());
    $agreement->setShippingAddress($this->shippingAddress());
    $agreement = $agreement->create($this->apiContext);
    
    return $agreement->getApprovalLink();
}

protected function Plan($id)
{
    $plan = new Plan();
    $plan->setId($id);
    
    return $plan;
}

protected function payer()
{
    $payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
    
    return $payer;
}

protected function shippingAddress()
{
    $shippingAddress = new ShippingAddress();
    $shippingAddress->setLine1('111 First Street')
        ->setCity('Saratoga')
        ->setState('CA')
        ->setPostalCode('95070')
        ->setCountryCode('US');
    
    return $shippingAddress;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a deprecated SDK that does not support the current version of [PayPal Subscriptions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/), for which there is no SDK.

Change your integration to not use that old SDK. The new Subscribe button itself is JavaScript. Use direct HTTPS calls with curl or similar when you need to call an API to create Products and Plans or administer Subscriptions.

(You can also do so in your account's web interface, rather than via API)

- Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/
- Live: https://www.paypal.com/billing/

Answer (score 0):

```html
protected function agreement($id) 
{
    $agreement = new Agreement();
    $agreement->setName('Base Agreement')->setDescription('Basic Agreement') 
    // ->setStartDate(date("Y-m-d").'T9:45:04Z'); ->setStartDate('2021-07-05T9:45:04Z');
    //Replace above line with below line
    //->setStartDate(gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time()+60));

    $agreement->setPlan($this->Plan($id));
    $agreement->setPayer($this->payer());
    $agreement->setShippingAddress($this->shippingAddress());
    $agreement = $agreement->create($this->apiContext);
    
    return $agreement->getApprovalLink();
}
```

1. You cannot comment on the start date of the agreement.
2. you must provide the start date of agreement and the error occurred due to this issue.